# Fetch the line that has two specific keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that contains pair of keywords ('k1', 'k2'). Here's a sample:

```
print (word_pairs)
--->[('salaire', 'dépense'), ('gratuité', 'argent'), ('causesmwedemwelamwemort', 'cadres'), ('caractèresmwedumwedispositif', 'historique'), ('psychomotricienmwediplôme', 'infirmier'), ('impôtmwesurmwelesmweréunionsmwesportives', 'compensation'), ('affichage', 'affichagemweopinion'), ('délaimweprorogation', 'défaillance'), ('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]
```

I have a text file `r_isa.txt` (205MB) that contain words that share an "isa" relationship. Here's a sample, where `\t` represents a literal tab character:

```
égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0
filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0
Loi reconnaissant l'égalité\tloi_1.0
égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0
liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0
```

This basically means, "égalité de Parseval" isa "formule" with a score of 0.9333 and isa "égalité" with a score of 1. And so go on..

I want to know based on the r_isa file, if the keyword `k1` isa `k2`, and if `k2` is-a `k1`. On the output file, I want to save on each line the pair of words that do have the is-a relationship.

Here's what I did:

```
#Reading data as list
keywords = [line for line in open('version_final_PMI_espace.txt', encoding='utf8')]
keywords = ast.literal_eval(keywords[0])
word_pairs = []

for k,v in keywords.items():
    if v:
        word_pairs.append((k,v[0][0]))
len(list(set(word_pairs)))
 #####  


with open("r_isa.txt",encoding="utf-8") as readfile, open('Hyperonymy_file_pair.txt', 'w') as writefile:
    for line in readfile:
        firstfield = line.split('\t')[0].lower()
        for w in word_pairs:
            if w[0]==firstfield:
                if w[1] in line: 
                    writefile.write("".join(w[0]) + "\t"+"".join(w[1]) +"\n" )
```

This returns random pairs to me, for exemple:

```
salaire\targent
dépense\tcadres
```

unstead of ( in case of an existing isa relationship)

```
salaire\tdépense
causesmwedemwelamwemort\tcadres
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: can you add expected output. how can someone understand `(k1,k6)(k1,k3) `

Comment: is there any chance one line can contain multiple pairs?

Comment: Please include more of your code, including how word_pairs gets filled in. For help, see this about a MVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @deadshot Thank you for your time. I edited the post with more details about the output. I checked but there's absolute no relationship between the pair it returns to me.

Comment: @NL5025 it could be better if you post the expected output that matches posted text file data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The statement `if w[1] in line:` is highly suspect. See the following code for what I believe the logic should be. Since I don't have access to your files, I have turned `readfile` into a list of strings for testing purposes and instead of writing output to `writefile`, I am just printing some results. I have added some values to `word_pairs` and `readfile` so that I get some results. Also note that if you are converting the input file to lower case, then your word pairs must also be lower case.

This code checks if k1 isa k2 and if not, then checks if k2 isa k1.

```
word_pairs = [('égalité de parseval', 'égalité'), ('salaire', 'dépense'), ('gratuité', 'argent'), ('causesmwedemwelamwemort', 'cadres'), ('caractèresmwedumwedispositif', 'historique'), ('psychomotricienmwediplôme', 'infirmier'), ('impôtmwesurmwelesmweréunionsmwesportives', 'compensation'), ('affichage', 'affichagemweopinion'), ('délaimweprorogation', 'défaillance'), ('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]
word_pairs2 = [(pair[1], pair[0]) for pair in word_pairs] # reverse the words
word_dict = dict(word_pairs) # create a dictionary for fast searching
word_dict2 = dict(word_pairs2)

readfile = [
    'égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0',
    'filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0',
    'Loi reconnaissant l\'égalité\tloi_1.0',
    'égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0',
    'liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0',
    'dépense\tsalaire_.9'
]

for line in readfile:
    fields = line.lower().split('\t')
    first_word = fields.pop(0)
    isa_word = word_dict.get(first_word, word_dict2.get(first_word)) # check k2 isa k1 if k1 isa k2 is false
    if isa_word is not None:
        for field in fields: # check each one
            fields2 = field.split('_')
            second_word, score = fields2
            if second_word == isa_word:
                print(first_word, second_word, score)
```

Prints:

```
égalité de parseval égalité 1.0
dépense salaire .9
```

If it is possible that k1 isa k2 *and* k2 isa k1, then you need the more general (but more complicated) code:

```
word_pairs = [('égalité de parseval', 'égalité'), ('salaire', 'dépense'), ('gratuité', 'argent'), ('causesmwedemwelamwemort', 'cadres'), ('caractèresmwedumwedispositif', 'historique'), ('psychomotricienmwediplôme', 'infirmier'), ('impôtmwesurmwelesmweréunionsmwesportives', 'compensation'), ('affichage', 'affichagemweopinion'), ('délaimweprorogation', 'défaillance'), ('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]
word_pairs2 = [(pair[1], pair[0]) for pair in word_pairs] # reverse the words
word_dict = dict(word_pairs) # create a dictionary for fast searching
word_dict2 = dict(word_pairs2)

readfile = [
    'égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0',
    'filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0',
    'Loi reconnaissant l\'égalité\tloi_1.0',
    'égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0',
    'liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0',
    'salaire\tdépense_1.0',
    'dépense\tsalaire_.9'
]

for line in readfile:
    fields = line.lower().split('\t')
    first_word = fields.pop(0)
    # k1 isa k2?
    isa_word = word_dict.get(first_word)
    if isa_word is not None:
        for field in fields: # check each one
            fields2 = field.split('_')
            second_word, score = fields2
            if second_word == isa_word:
                print(first_word, second_word, score)
    # k2 isa k1?
    isa_word = word_dict2.get(first_word)
    if isa_word is not None:
        for field in fields: # check each one
            fields2 = field.split('_')
            second_word, score = fields2
            if second_word == isa_word:
                print(first_word, second_word, score)
```

Prints:

```
égalité de parseval égalité 1.0
salaire dépense 1.0
dépense salaire .9
```

Comment: Thank you. This is for the case k1 isa k2 with the pair being (k1,k2). If I want to see if k2 isa k1 how do you advice me to proceed ?( based on your code)

Comment: I've updated the answer with two variations depending upon whether k1 isa k2 and k2 isa k1 can both be True simultaneously or not. The second variation is more general and will always be correct regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
kw = [('salaire', 'dépense'),
      ('gratuité', 'argent'),
      ('causesmwedemwelamwemort', 'cadres'),
      ('caractèresmwedumwedispositif', 'historique'),
      ('psychomotricienmwediplôme', 'infirmier'),
      ('impôtmwesurmwelesmweréunionsmwesportives', 'compensation'),
      ('affichage', 'affichagemweopinion'),
      ('délaimweprorogation', 'défaillance'),
      ('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]

lines_from_file = ['égalité de Parseval\tformule_0.9333\tégalité_1.0',
                   'filiation illégitime\tfiliation_1.0',
                   'Loi reconnaissant l\'égalité\tloi_1.0',
                   'égalité entre les sexes\tégalité_1.0',
                   'liberté égalité fraternité\tliberté_1.0',
                   'créancemwenotion\tgénéralités_1.0',
                   'généralités\tcréancemwenotion_1.0']

who_is_who_dict = {}
for line in lines_from_file:
    words = line.split('\t')
    key = words[0]
    other_words = [w.split('_')[0] for w in words[1:]]
    if key in who_is_who_dict:
        who_is_who_dict[key] = who_is_who_dict[key] + other_words
    else:
        who_is_who_dict[key] = other_words

pairs_to_write = []
for kw1, kw2 in kw:
    if (kw1 in who_is_who_dict and kw2 in who_is_who_dict[kw1]
            and kw2 in who_is_who_dict and kw1 in who_is_who_dict[kw2]):
        pairs_to_write.append((kw1, kw2))

print(pairs_to_write)
```

output :

```
[('créancemwenotion', 'généralités')]
```